# Передвижение мыши на объект в клиентском приложении Python

Tags: python, мышь

Суть проблемы в том, что часть объектов периодически меняет свое местоположение на экране, и на двух моих компах разные мониторы и, соответственно, разрешение. Поэтому я не могу пользоваться считыванием координат позиции указателя мыши. По крайней мере для части объектов. Единственное, что пришло мне в голову - это считывание rgb кода пикселя под указателем мыши, и затем передвижение мыши на этот пиксель. И я не знаю, возможно ли это на Python. Делал я следующее:
Для считывания координат указателя и кода пикселя

```
x, y = pyautogui.position()
positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
pixelColor = pyautogui.screenshot().getpixel((x, y))
positionStr += ' RGB: (' + str(pixelColor[0]).rjust(3)
positionStr += ', ' + str(pixelColor[1]).rjust(3)
positionStr += ', ' + str(pixelColor[2]).rjust(3) + ')'
print(positionStr, end='')
```

Но это мало что мне дало, на самом деле. Теоретически, можно воспользоваться

```
pyautogui.moveTo(int(pyautogui.center(pyautogui.locateOnScreen('картинка'))[0]),
                int(pyautogui.center(pyautogui.locateOnScreen('картинка'))[1]) , duration = random.randint(2,5))
```

Но тут уже встает проблема разрешения. т.е., скрипт не находит картинку на втором мониторе, если скрин был сделан на первом.